# Horizontal form + inline form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the form user profile on a bootstrap with horizontal form and inline form, but they do not work together.

[image: It is a normal width]

[image: It is a small window width]

It is my code:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: edit_project_user_path, html: { method: :put, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" } do |user_fields| %>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 margin-top-20 margin-bottom-20">
              <%= image_tag("user_no_foto.jpg", alt: "Avatar", class: "img-circle avatar-lg center-block") %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 margin-bottom-20 text-muted">
              <h4>Аккаунт</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Эл. почта*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Пароль*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 border-row margin-bottom-40 margin-top-40"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 margin-bottom-20 text-muted">
              <h4>Информация о пользователе</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLastName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Фамилия*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Имя*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMiddleName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Отчество</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputMiddleName" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата рождения*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 border-row margin-bottom-40 margin-top-40"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 margin-bottom-20 text-muted">
              <h4>Дополнительные адреса эл. почты</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <span class="col-sm-3 control-label">Доп. почта</span>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputKey" class="sr-only">Key</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Key">
                </div>
                <label for="inputValue" class="sr-only">Value</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Why it lost the interval between inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To arrange input box itself in responsive layout, set bottom-margin. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `bottom-margin` for input box, so that it will arrange itself in responsive layout.